# non linear system of differential equations

Tags: python, scipy, ode

i'm trying to solve the following non linear system of differential equations
but i don't understand where is the problem in the code that i wrote.
The system is non linear with complex coefficients and complex domain.

```
from pylab import *
from scipy.integrate import ode

#------initial parameters------
c = 3 * 10 ** 8
h = 6.626 / (2 * pi) * 10 ** -34
kb = 1.3806 * 10 ** -23
TT = 0.1
mm = 1.50 * 10 ** -10
wM = 2 * pi * 10 ** 6
gM = 2 * pi * 10 ** 2
ll = 1064 * 10 ** -9
PL = 100 * 10 ** -4
L = 0.025
k = 1.340 * 10 ** 7
D0 = wM
Ns = 2083
wL = 2 * pi * c / ll
wC = D0 + wL
aL = sqrt((2 * k * PL) / (h * wL))
G0 = wC / L * sqrt(h / (mm * wM))
tau = 1 / k

tciclo = 3 * pi / wM
tauP = 0.5 * pi / wM
tauNP = tciclo - tauP
dtau = 1 / (10 * k)


def fun(t, y, wM,gM,G0,k,D0,aL):
    return [wM * y[1],
            -wM * y[0] - gM * y[1] + G0 * y[2]*y[2].conjugate(),
            -(k + 1j * D0) * y[2] + 1j * G0 * y[0] * y[2]+aL]


y0 = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]

r = ode(f).set_integrator('zvode', method='bdf')
r.set_initial_value(y0, 0).set_f_params(2.0)

tt = []
yy = []
while r.successful() and r.t < tauP:
    r.integrate(r.t + dtau)
    tt.append(r.t)
    yy.append(r.y)

plot(tt, yy)
show()
```

Comment: traceback or any error messages?

Comment: You typoed `ode(f)` when you should have `ode(fun)`. `f` comes from `from pylab import *` and is a function that calculates a random variable from the f-distribution... Your second problem is that `def fun(t, y, ...)` includes a large list of additional arguments but you give only one value in `set_f_params`.

Answer (score 0):

Always include the error message in your question.  If you don't have any errors, include the output that you got, and explain why it is not what you expected.

Having said that...  I see at least one problem with your code.  `fun` has the standard `t` and `y` arguments, followed by the parameters `wM,gM,G0,k,D0,aL`.  You must specify a value for each of these parameters in the call to `set_f_params()`.  You currently have `set_f_params(2.0)`, but that call needs six arguments to match the extra parameters of `fun`.

In a comment, @pv. has pointed out a second problem:  `ode(f)` should be `ode(fun)`.

Comment: Thank you for responding so quickly. I noticed the typo as soon as I posted the question.
I have set the parameters and now all is right.

Comment: I have another question: How can i solve the system above in the case of aL defined as a periodic step function?

Comment: The comments are not the right place to address that question.  Instead, create a new question.